# How to make * operator working with generic variables in java? - if I know the variable is numeric type

Tags: java, generic-programming

There is my generic class. I try to create and call length method on it in main and i get [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNINm.png) if some value passed to constructor is Integer. If all three parameters are double it is OK. I also tried using * operator instead of Math.pow, but it is not working either, because * is undefined for the argument N. So... basically how do i multiply generic variables if i know they are numeric type - "Number"

```
public class Test<N>{

    public N x;
    public N y;
    public N z;
    public Test(N arg1, N arg2, N arg3)
    {
        if (!(arg1 instanceof Number) || !(arg2 instanceof Number) || !(arg3 instanceof Number))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("OK");
            this.x = arg1;
            this.y = arg2;
            this.z = arg3;
        }
    }

    public double length()
    {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((double)x, 2) + Math.pow((double)y, 2) + Math.pow((double)z, 2));
    }
}

Main:
System.out.println(new Test<>(2.56898,5.45,4.41).length());    // OK
System.out.println(new Test<>(2.56898,5,4).length());   // EXCEPTION
```

Comment: If the type argument must be a subtype of `Number` then you should use `Test<N extends Number>`. Then you can call the appropriate methods on the `Number` instances (e.g. `x.doubleValue()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just specify the subtype of your generic, e.g.

```
public class Test<N extends Number> {
...
}
```

And then, instead of casting in `length` method, you use appropriate method `doubleValue()` or whatever you will need in future, e.g.

```
public double length() {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x.doubleValue(), 2) + Math.pow(y.doubleValue(), 2) + Math.pow(z.doubleValue(), 2));
}
```